# What JavaScript/CSS solutions can I use to make an interactive emblem website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a bit of experience in basic vanilla JavaScript. I want to create a website that would help with the study of the Qabalistic Tree of Life. The Tree of Life looks like this:

[image: Tree of life]

The idea is for the emblem to be at the centre of the starting page. The spheres and paths are to be clickable. On hover, they are to display the name of the sphere/path and preferably have an animation. On click, they take the user to another page that is dedicated to the subject of the sphere or path.

My main concern is that I do not know how to design the page with the emblem and make it interactive with animations. I was thinking about dividing the HTML into a table and placing each of the spheres in respective cells, but that seems like a tedious process and the paths will not work that way.

What tools could I employ to go about this? A JS library perhaps? I am by no means advanced (want to use this as practice) so the simplest solution would be most appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I would either use d3.js or Greensock.js, the choice to use Greensock would be determined by how powerful do your animation capabilities have to be?

Comment: I would also consider if I should draw the tree of life as an SVG, since it seems pretty simple.

Comment: I think this is a good fit for SVG graphics and you can have animations and interactivity using javascript https://www.jonathan-petitcolas.com/2013/07/18/create-clickable-svg-france-regions-map.html

Comment: You could create the tree with SVG. Each part of the SVG that you wish to animate can be given a class which you can use to create CSS animations. Here is an example of SVG links for on click https://alligator.io/svg/hyperlinks-svg/

Comment: I would consider using a canvas here and writing my own graphics. You can achieve this with CSS/JS as well though.